# Creating JPG thumbnails from PDF causes problems with new version of ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, paperclip, thumbnails, ghostscript

I'm using Imagemagick to create thumbnails images of pdf files with this command:

```
convert 'input.pdf[0]' -resize "100x140>" -colorspace 'rgb' 'output.jpg' 2>/dev/null
```

Some of the PDFs are in CMYK color space, hence the specification of the expected -colorspace as rgb. This was working fine until I updated to the latest versions of Imagemagick(6.6.7-1) and ghostscript(9.01_0), now it looks like the conversion to rgb isn't working any longer, here is an example output:

[image: failed cymk-rgb conversion]

(The background should be white, not black)
It seems though that the problem comes from the -resize option because if I remove it the output is correct.

To get the expected output I now do two passes, the first to convert to rgb and the second to resize the image, but that's not very elegant. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Tested with imagemagick 6.6.5-6 and 6.6.7-6 and I confirm this problem, the later one goes black background while the old one works as expected.

Comment: I have the same issue with 6.6.7-10 and gs 9.01.

Comment: Same here with ImageMagick 6.7.4-0 and gs 9.04. Any hint on how to solve that ?

Comment: I got a smilar problem, using graphicsmagick solved it

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by passing the extra `-flatten` option. Now my thumbnails are render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What if you swap options? This may save you from running the 2 different commands. Because these two commands:

```
convert 'in.pdf[0]' -resize "100x140>" -colorspace 'rgb' 'out.jpg'
convert 'in.pdf[0]' -colorspace 'rgb' -resize "100x140>" 'out.jpg'
```

will cause (recent versions of) ImageMagick to process the files in a different way; it each times follows the order given on the commandline (this is not true for older versions).