# sfThumbnailPlugin black background for transparent parts

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, symfony-1.4, thumbnails

I'm using sfThumbnail-Plugin (Version 2.0.1) in my Symfony 1.4-project, to create thumbnails for uploaded PDF-files. Unfortunately transparent parts, i.E. the background, of the documents (which are shown white in all the usual PDF-viewers) are converted to black in the thumbnails.

Is there any way to fix this?

My code:

```
$t = new sfThumbnail(134, 190, true, true, 75, 'sfImageMagickAdapter', array('extract' => 1));
$t->loadFile(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . "/path/" . $this->getObject()->pdf);
$t->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/path/' . $this->getObject()->pdf . '.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant provide a working code for this, but you might consider using pngs, which support transparency, as suggested here:

[ImageMagick PDF to JPGs sometimes results in black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934456/imagemagick-pdf-to-jpgs-sometimes-results-in-black-background)

Further you can try to add the flatten option as described here:
[Creating JPG thumbnails from PDF causes problems with new version of ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028208/creating-jpg-thumbnails-from-pdf-causes-problems-with-new-version-of-imagemagick/5029071#5029071)

You can pass the additional options in the 7th param of the like this (untested, thou)

```
$t = new sfThumbnail(134, 190, true, true, 75, 'sfImageMagickAdapter', array('extract' => 1, 'flatten' => true)
```

Comment: I thought about this, but using anything else then jpg is not possible within this application. :(
'flatten' => true  also does not work. Do you know if this is the right way to pass a param that can't have a value?

Comment: try this: ```$t = new sfThumbnail(134, 190, true, true, 75, 'sfImageMagickAdapter', array('extract' => 1, 'convert' => 'convert -flatten'));```