# Make JPG thumbnails of PDF in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, imagemagick, typo3-11.x

Using the File Links element with thumbnails, PDF files render PNG thumbnails which are quite large in file size.

Is there any way to make TYPO3 render JPG thumbnails instead?

The only setting seems to be `[GFX][thumbnails_png]` which limits it to either a GIF or PNG.

Comment: @KJ PNG: 80kb, JPG: 8kb, so basically 10 times faster loading for a whole list of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using FluidStyledContent. The link list has the following template or line ([Templates/Uploads.html, line 17](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/fluid_styled_content/blob/main/Resources/Private/Templates/Uploads.html#L17)):

```
<a href="{file.publicUrl}" {f:if(condition:data.target,then: ' target="{data.target}"')}{f:if(condition: file.title, then: ' title="{file.title}"')}>
   <f:media file="{file}" width="150" alt="{file.properties.alternative}" />
</a>
```

You can add a [`fileExtension`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/12.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Media.html#fileextension) attribute to the media-ViewHelper. So if you explicitly request "jpg" there, then JPGs should come out.

This attribute has been introduced in TYPO3 10.3 ([Feature #90416](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Feature-90416-SpecificTargetFileExtensionInImage-relatedViewHelpers.html))

Comment: Great thank you. Only, it renders the background black. I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809692/why-do-imagemagick-based-thumbnail-images-of-pdf-files-in-typo3-have-black-backg) but it seems a bit hacky, is it really the only way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know the problem, but I haven't used PDFs as a basis for a long time either... And, yes, the linked "solution" sounds very hacky (and is quite old). I just tested in v12: PDF thumbnails look clean for me.
What does "Admin Tools > Environment > Image Processing" under "Read PDF" say? Does it look clean?

Comment: The Image Processing test for PDF looks good. Command: `'/usr/bin/convert' -interlace None -auto-orient +profile '*' -auto-orient -geometry 300x425! -colorspace RGB -quality 85  -colorspace RGB` . With my thumbnails I also notice they are very chunky as jpg like there is no antialiasing or something.

Comment: @KJ Not compression artifacts, chunky like text appearing as solid bars of colour, like it has been resized very badly.